# Networking ( file share ) using a LAN cable in 18.04

Tags: networking, 18.04, samba, ethernet

I have 2 PCs, both running 18.04. I want to connect them using a normal LAN cable and share files between them. `PC 2` has `Samba` and a folder is shared. `PC 2` is kind of my storage PC and transfer through WiFi is very slow.

Is it possible without any router in between ?

If no, I have a spare router, how should I use it ?

Comment: Yes, you can do this, but you need to set static IPs on both systems.  Are you using the GUI?

Comment: Yes, I have GUI. I can set static IP on both. Thanks, I will try.

Comment: Set a static IP on both Ethernet interfaces within the same subnet but with different addresses (192.168.234.10 and 192.168.234.11, with a subnet mask of 255.255.255.0 on both, no gateway, as an example).  Then hook the two systems up with an ethernet cable.  Then point the share/sync bits at the IPs directly.

Comment: "  Then point the share/sync bits at the IPs directly. ", not sure how to do this. In WiFi, I can see the shared folder of `PC 2` in " Other locations " of `PC 1`

Comment: AH, well that's using network discovery, it should be able to see itself automatically then, I believe.  However, if it doesn't, you might have to manually connect to the shares by IP.

Comment: How can I manually connect ?

Comment: On older hardware you need a cross-over cable and not a normal LAN cable. But ethernet hardware from the last 10 years should have the cross-over feature build in.

Comment: Both PCs has working ethernet ports and WiFi adapters.

Comment: I connected 2 machines with LAN cable in as-is condition of 2 PCs. `PC 1` was not able to see `PC 2`. Neither ping it with the static IP of `PC 2`. But the subnet on `PC 2` was 0.0.0.0 ( which works while in WiFi network ). It was a real-world simple test, replace wifi with RJ45 without a router it didn't work. Hopefully, I can fix it at another occasion.